# Filter a struct array according to a NSPredicate SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, filter, uisearchcontroller

I have an `UITableView` and an `UISearchController`. I want to filter my array of data (named: allGames)  according to the `NSPredicate` of the `UISearchBar.text`.

My code only filter an array of string like this:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    filteredGames.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (allGames).filtered(using: searchPredicate)

    filteredGames = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Here I can filter my array. But if I create this struct:

```
struct Games {

    var name: String?
    var type: String?
    var image: UIImage?
}
```

How can I filter the array according to the game names and types? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search Bar Swift 3 - Can't use in/contains operator with collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308007/search-bar-swift-3-cant-use-in-contains-operator-with-collection) – You can't use NSPredicate with an array of structs.

Comment: See also [Swift - Search using UISearchController and NSPredicate with an array of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556328/swift-search-using-uisearchcontroller-and-nspredicate-with-an-array-of-structs) or [Search for struct in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360226/search-for-struct-in-swift).

Comment: Oh I read a lot of question and didn't find these questions!

Comment: Just search for [`[swift] struct array nspredicate`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+struct+array+nspredicate) ... And don't introduce your question with *"this is not a duplicate"* :)

Comment: Ahah ok I will remember this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `allGames` is an array `[Games]` – by the way the struct is supposed to be named in singular form `Game` – I highly recommend to use the native Swift `filter` function

```
let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text!
let fileredGames = allGames.filter { $0.name?.range(of: searchText, options: [.caseInsensitive]) != nil 
                                  || $0.type?.range(of: searchText, options: [.caseInsensitive]) != nil }
```

Consider also to declare `type` and `name` in the struct as non-optional.

Comment: It looks like it works well. I named my array allGames to make the difference with filteredGames. You mean it's better the create initiated variables in my struct? Like `let name: String = ""` ?

Comment: No, there is a general misunderstanding. Many people mean (and suggest in tutorials) that you can't declare properties non-optional (no exclamation or question mark) without an initializer. That's correct in case of a class, but in a struct **you can** because there is the implicit memberwise initializer. You can even declare the property as constant `let name: String` if the value is supposed not to be changed.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks